# Json error when bundling in last version of react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I recently updated an old project on react native. When i installed it on a colleague computer it worked fine but after i pulling it on mine I'm not able to bundle the program.

When executing "react-native run-android" I get :

```sh
error TypeError: _rxjs.Observable.interval is not a function
    at Device._setPagesPolling (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\Device.js:266:22)
    at new Device (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\Device.js:108:10)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:239:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:14:24)
    at _next (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:34:9)
    at P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:39:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:31:12)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:255:24)
(node:1436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of TypeError
    at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:727:11)
    at Sender.close (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\ws\lib\Sender.js:52:50)
    at WebSocket.close (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:122:18)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:250:20)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:14:24)
    at _next (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:34:9)
    at P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:39:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-inspector-proxy\src\InspectorProxy.js:31:12)
(node:1436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1436) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[Fri Jul 17 2020 16:31:10.855]  BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

on the node shell.

And when I just try to bundle it I get :

```sh
error Unexpected end of JSON input. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Package.read (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\Package.js:146:28)
    at Package.getMain (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\Package.js:55:23)
    at Object.getPackageMainPath (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:83:23)
    at resolvePackage (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:308:34)
    at resolveDir (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:290:24)
    at resolveFileOrDir (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:264:21)
    at Object.resolve (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:151:20)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:143:31)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (P:\Mobile App\fy-remote\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
```

I asked colleague and it worked fine on their computer, and other react-native projet work well on mine. So I have no idea what to reinstall or fix.

If anyone can guide me.

EDIT :

App.json

```
{
  "name": "FyRemote",
  "displayName": "FyRemote"
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "FyRemote",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install fs,dgram,process,path,console --hack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.1.5",
    "asyncstorage-down": "^4.2.0",
    "buffer": "^4.9.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "mqtt": "^3.0.0",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-easy-gestures": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-gateway-finder": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-path": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-webpack": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^5.6.12",
    "redux-persist-transform-filter": "0.0.18",
    "require-context": "^1.1.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "rn-nodeify": "github:mvayngrib/rn-nodeify"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp"
  },
  "browser": {
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your project have a `package-lock.json`? Do you have the same node version as your colleague?

Comment: Please, add your `app.json` and your `package.json` file here?

Comment: here they are do you see anything ?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out this is due to a flawed installation of the module.

To solve this you need to use "npm ci" instead.